# M2M field widget to add or update data as inline formset

Tags: python, django, m2m

I spent a lot of hours searching for a feature which I think should be quite a basic functionality in Django. But I just can't get it working,

I am unable to find a widget which will function same as m2m widget of django, but will also create new model instance if it doesn't exists.

**Note:** Here model instance already exists means that data entered in inline widget already exists in database.

E.g.
If I had models as:

```
class Outcome(models.Model):
    outcome = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    outcome_short_name = models.CharField(max_length=10, blank=True, null=True)


class Course(models.Model):
    course_title = models.CharField(
        verbose_name=COURSE_SINGULAR + " title", max_length=200, unique=True
    )

    course_outcome = models.ManyToManyField(
        Outcome, verbose_name=COURSE_SINGULAR + " outcome", blank=True
    )
```

Then I want "Outcomes" shown as this image while creating course:
[Image of adding new course with inline outcomes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/77wrv.png)

Now, If the outcomes data added by user already exists, then it should only map them to course. Otherwise it should first store outcomes into database and then map them to course.

Any guidance in right direction will be highly appreciated.

Thanks,

**EDIT:**
As suggested by @dirkgroten to use modelformset, I changed my FormView as:

```
class CourseFormView(FormView):
    template_name = "course/course_form.html"
    form_class = CourseForm
    success_url = "/admin/"

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(CourseFormView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        if self.request.POST:
            context["outcomes"] = OutcomeFormSet(self.request.POST)
        else:
            context["outcomes"] = OutcomeFormSet(queryset=Outcome.objects.none())
        return context

    def form_valid(self, form, **kwargs):
        super(CourseFormView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context = self.get_context_data()
        outcomes_formset = context["outcomes"]
        if not outcomes_formset.is_valid():
            return super().form_invalid(form)

        cleaned_data = form.cleaned_data
        cleaned_data.pop("course_outcome")
        course = Course.objects.create(**cleaned_data)
        course.save()

        outcomes_formset.instance = course
        outcomes_formset.save()


course.course_outcome.set(Outcome.objects.filter(course_outcome=course))
    return super().form_valid(form)
```

Everything looks fine except my model_formset is not validated if form data in formset already exists in database.
E.g. if I enter (outcome="test_outcome", outcome_short_name="test_short") in formset and same data already exists in outcome table, then my formset gives error:
Outcome with this Outcome and Outcome short name already exists.

Is there any way to tackle this situation or I am doing something wrong.

You can test above at: http://code.gdy.club:8001/course/add/
outcomes_list: http://code.gdy.club:8001/outcome/

Thanks,

--
Suraj
https://hacksj4u.wordpress.com
https://github.com/SurajDadral

Comment: It looks like you want to use a [`ModelFormset`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/topics/forms/modelforms/#model-formsets). Then for the `ModelForm`, change its save() method to check whether it should create a new object or just use the existing one. Note that what "existing one" means isn't clear from your question, as the model has two fields. Do both fields need to match? Or only one of them?

Comment: Thanks @dirkgroten for your guidance. I will look into it if it satisfy my requirements and will let you know. I also added note to clarify about "existing one".

Comment: @dirkgroten, I tried using modelformset, but it gives error as described in edit section above. Thanks

Comment: So contrary to what you show up here, you made the `outcome` and `outcome_short_name` fields in your `Outcome` model unique?

Comment: @dirkgroten Yes, but if I don't make them then I get IntegrityError (1062, "Duplicate entry 'test_ou6-tstou6-ac_tmp6' for key 'course_outcome_outcome_outcome_short_na_af250734_uniq'")

But that is on saving, so I think making fields non-unique in model will resolve my issue

I will let you know soon. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to handle the case where an `Outcome` already exists yourself. The default when validating the form is to assume a new object will be created, so if your fields are set to be `unique_together`, then the individual form will not validate.

You could do it on the `OutcomeFormset`'s `clean()` method like this:

```
from django.core.exceptions import NON_FIELD_ERRORS

def clean(self):
    super().clean()
    for i in range(0, self.total_form_count()):
        form = self.forms[i]
        if form.non_field_errors() and len(form.errors) == 1:
            # the only error is probably due to unique_together constraint
            try:
                form.instance = Outcome.objects.get(
                    outcome=form.data.get(form.add_prefix('outcome')),
                    outcome_short_name=form.data.get(form.add_prefix('outcome_short_name')))
            except Outcome.DoesNotExist:
                pass  # some other error so we should keep it
            else:
                del form._errors[NON_FIELD_ERRORS]
```

Then in your view, when saving the formset, you should loop through all forms and not save the ones where the instance has a `pk`:

```
for form in outcomes_formset:
    outcome = form.instance    
    if not outcome.pk:
        outcome = form.save()
    course.course_outcome.add(outcome)
```

Comment: Thanks @dirkgroten, above worked for me.
I need to change a little in for loop in clean method as:
Outcome.objects.get(outcome=form.data.get("form-" + str(i) + "-outcome"),outcome_short_name=form.data.get("form-" + str(i) + "-outcome_short_name"))  

And remove super().clean()

Thanks for your precious time and efforts.

Comment: Right, forgot about the form prefix. Fixed now.

Comment: I implemented another way discussed by you in your first comment as per commit: https://github.com/GreatDevelopers/OutcomeBasedCourse/commit/e6f0530ed6054055d55a596e9d390fbf05727f01

Thanks for your guidance

Comment: Great. Just one note: never catch all exceptions with just `except:`. Always specify which exception you’re catching like this: `except Outcome.DoesNotExist:`. That’s because if there’s another exception you want it to raise since you don’t know how to handle it.

Comment: Thanks for your great suggestion. This helped me finding and fixing new errors. Incorporated above suggestion as here: https://github.com/GreatDevelopers/OutcomeBasedCourse/blob/master/course/views.py#L414